# HTML5/Canvas Mouse Position off when placed in actual Site

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, mouse-position

I'm capturing mouse position like this

```
    mouse_move: function(e)
    {
        mousePos.x = e.pageX - vr.o.context.canvas.offsetLeft;
        mousePos.y = e.pageY - vr.o.context.canvas.offsetTop;
    },
```

and it has worked like a dream in all modern browsers while in development, Even tested Wrapping the `<canvas/>` in a basic dom structure to make sure mouse position adjusted...

obviously now I'm putting it in the actual site it's not working...

You can see here http://jondavidjohn.com/projects/

the mouse position ends up quite a ways south of the actual cursor, anything specifically that could be causing this?

***SOLUTION***

```
mouse_move: function(e)
{
    mousePos.x = e.offsetX;
    mousePos.y = e.offsetY;
},
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

COPIED FROM:  http://simonsarris.com/blog/510-making-html5-canvas-useful

Getting mouse coordinates on Canvas

Getting good mouse coordinates is a little tricky on Canvas. You could use offsetX/Y and LayerX/Y, but LayerX/Y is deprecated in webkit (Chrome and Safari) and Firefox does not have offsetX/Y.

The most bulletproof way to get the correct mouse position is shown below. You have to walk up the tree adding the offsets together. Then you must add any padding or border to the offset. Finally, to fix coordinate problems when you have fixed-position elements on the page (like the wordpress admin bar or a stumbleupon bar) you must add the ’s offsetTop and offsetLeft.

Then you simply subtract that offset from the e.pageX/Y values and you’ll get perfect coordinates in almost every possible situation.

```
// Creates an object with x and y defined,
// set to the mouse position relative to the state's canvas
// If you wanna be super-correct this can be tricky,
// we have to worry about padding and borders
CanvasState.prototype.getMouse = function(e) {
  var element = this.canvas, offsetX = 0, offsetY = 0, mx, my;

  // Compute the total offset
  if (element.offsetParent !== undefined) {
    do {
      offsetX += element.offsetLeft;
      offsetY += element.offsetTop;
    } while ((element = element.offsetParent));
  }

  // Add padding and border style widths to offset
  // Also add the <html> offsets in case there's a position:fixed bar
  offsetX += this.stylePaddingLeft + this.styleBorderLeft + this.htmlLeft;
  offsetY += this.stylePaddingTop + this.styleBorderTop + this.htmlTop;

  mx = e.pageX - offsetX;
  my = e.pageY - offsetY;

  // We return a simple javascript object (a hash) with x and y defined
  return {x: mx, y: my};
}
```

Comment: haha, that's hilarious, an answer competing with @SimonSarris from his own blog... ...akward...

Comment: Not competing - just updating the thread to include Simon's code that he referred to in his post :)

Comment: Good job @chopperdave, I had forgotten about this Q and never got him the complete code!

Answer (score 2):

Use e.offsetX and e.offsetY for now instead.

It actually gets more complicated when you introduce some other things, like margins and padding, but offsetX and offsetY will be much more accurate than what you've got to say the least.

I don't have my new "bulletproof-works-in-every-situation" mouse code on me right now, I can get that later for you if you think you'll need it.

*edit: Derp! Thanks chopperdave for finally providing the code I forgot to add!*

Comment: Yes, border and padding on the canvas itself will screw things up.